# System.NullPointerException on trigger.old

Tags: apex, trigger

I am very new Apex Triggers, please some guidance is required it is giving me an error

caused by:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.UpdateLeadSource: line 3, column 1

```
trigger UpdateLeadSource on Lead (before insert, before update) {

if(trigger.old[0].LeadSource == null &&

trigger.old[0].Lead_Sources_For_Career_Advisor__c != trigger.new[0].Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c
)
{
 trigger.new[0].LeadSource = trigger.new[0].Lead_Sources_For_Career_Advisor__c ; 
}
else if(trigger.old[0].LeadSource == null &&
trigger.old[0].Lead_Source_for_Employer__c != trigger.new[0].Lead_Source_for_Employer__c
)
{
 trigger.new[0].LeadSource = trigger.new[0].Lead_Source_for_Employer__c ;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it your full code?

Comment: Remove the before insert.

Comment: trigger needs to be bulkified -- you don't want to use [0] to reference the triggered list element as the trigger can execute with many records such as via a Data Loader operation. SFDC idiom in coding triggers is to always think in terms of lists and maps.  Search on 'bulkify' to see many examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this exception:
1. Remove "before insert" keyword.

```
trigger UpdateLeadSource on Lead (before update) { .... }
```

2. Add criterion in if...else statement

   ```
   String oldLeaderSource = trigger.old[0].Lead_Sources_For_Career_Advisor__c;
   String newLeaderSource = trigger.new[0].Lead_Sources_for_Career_Advisor__c;
   if(trigger.old[0].LeadSource == null && (Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate && oldLeaderSource != newLeaderSource))){ ...... }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Triggers will operate on a bunch of records. not just 1 record. so don't just process/work on only the 1st record. iterate the entire list of new / old records.

Your trigger runs on both before **insert and update**, but you cant access **trigger.old** for insert (as there is no previous values to store)

for future references, you can go thru these links to understand more on the [trigger context](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) variables and some [best practices](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm) on triggers.

Also, for me it looks like you can use **Workflow Rule + Field Update** to achieve your requirement. you don't need a trigger for this scenario.

Comment: Yes this is the full code

Comment: +1 for recommending a Workflow Rule instead of a trigger for this action. It will be easier and quicker to write.